# elasticsearch nGram/edgengram partial match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, lucene, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to make **partial search** working, a search for

*"sw"
"swe"
"swed*"

should match *"Sweden"*

I looked around and just can't get it to work

[Rails Code](https://gist.github.com/2924440)

I'm using 
[this code](https://gist.github.com/2924468) from the Tire repo as templatecode.

whole words still match!

I have reindex and also tried using the edgengram filter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Ruby developper but found this article useful:
http://dev.af83.com/2012/01/19/autocomplete-with-tire.html

Like it sais:

```
Most databases handle that feature with a filter (with LIKE keyword in SQL, regular expression search with mongoDB). The strategy is simple: iterate on all results and keep only words which match the filter. This is brutal and hurts the hard drive. Elastic Search can do it too, with the prefix query.

With a small index, it plays well. For large indexes it will be more slow and painful.
```

---

You said:

```
whole words still match!
```

And what do you expect? Is "Sweden" not supposed to match "Sweden" but only "Swe", "Swed" or Swede" ?
Because your query on the field is also analyzed

Answer (score 1):

Use the [edgengram token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/edgengram-tokenfilter/). That will get you what you're looking for.